# While loop never exits for EOF

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop, eof

I'm writing my own shell in C and I need to detect EOF (for when I run `./myshell < commands.txt`)

commands.txt contains:

```
ls
pwd
```

These both run fine separately from within the program. But when I run it with the text file, I get an infinite loop.

In my `while(1)` loop for the shell, the first thing I do is this:

```
if (feof(stdin)) { my_exit(); }
```

`my_exit` is simply:

```
void my_exit() {
    printf("End of file! Bye\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Doesn't `exit(0)` end the program (and the loop)? Why am I getting

> End of File! ByeEnd of File! ByeEnd of File! ByeEnd of File! ByeEnd of File! ByeEnd of File! Bye.... etc

I have also tried doing the `fgets == NULL` way. Same loop

Comment: Yes, `exit(0)` should definitely exit the process.  Show us some more code.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing more code, but you should detect end-of-file by checking the value returned by whatever input function you're using. `feof()` and `ferror()` are for finding out why an input operation failed. If there's an input error, `ferror()` will return true and `feof()` will return false, which could give you an infinite loop.

Comment: I've added the rest of my code - I also tried doing this detection with fgets == NULL, still resulted in an infinite loop, no exit. Weird thing is, it prints out the exit text... so it's hitting that function, but exit(0) isn't ending the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `feof()` tells you if the LAST input operation ran into EOF. But you're not checking this until the next iteration. So when you're at EOF, you do `fgets()` and then try to use the empty result that it returned.

What's happening is that you `fork()` a child process, and then call `execvp()` with an empty command name. This is failing, so the child process returns to the beginning of the loop, and does the same thing. Meanwhile, the parent process calls `my_exit()`. So each child process forks another child of its own, and then exits.

Comment: So, don't bother to capture the result of `execvp()`; if it returns, it failed.  Consider reporting the failure and `exit(1);` to indicate the failure — all in the block that represents the child process.  You could also include the current process ID in the prompt, at least as a debugging measure.

Comment: Basically, this program is missing lots of error checking. It's common to omit this in toy programs, but in this case it would have helped find the problem. You need to check for `fgets()` returning an error so you skip the rest of the loop body, and for `execvp()` returning anything so you don't resume the loop in the child.

Answer (score 0):

The way feof works is that it returns false as long as no read has hit EOF. feof by itself does not check the stream, but checks if EOF indicator has been set, which happens when something like fgets fails.

It really is not a very good practice to use feof in the control loop.

An example of validating EOF can be this:

```
while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL )
  fputs(line, stdout);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try like this...

```
int a=1;
while(a)
{
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        a = 0;
    }
}
printf("End of file! Bye\n");
exit(0);
```

Comment: That will execute the rest of the loop body even though it's at EOF. Why not just use `break;` to exit the loop?